# Membership.CreateUser for multiple Membership Providers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am having trouble with handling multiple Membership Providers on one site.

I have a registration page that creates user and adds them to an AD domain. Before I had one membership provider and on the page I called

```
Membership.CreateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)
```

which created the username based on the user inputs on the page.

However, I added another membership provider to the web.config so that the log in page can be used to log in from another AD. Now, my registration page will not work because (I assume) there is two membership providers?

How can I fix this? How do I specify which provider to use when I call Membership.CreateUser?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

The correct way to do this, as mentioned below is :

```
MembershipCreateStatus newStatus = new MembershipCreateStatus();    
Membership.Providers["ProviderName"].CreateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, null, null, null, true,null, out newStatus);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Membership.Providers["providername"].CreateUser(....);
```

Note that there is only one CreateUser method in this case but you can pass null of other parameters that are not needed.

**Edit:**

That is the only way to call that method with explicit provider. I haven't tried creating user in AD so not sure about resolving that error but here is another way.
Make the provider for CreateUser as your defaultprovider and so you can go back to the old CreateUser call. But now you adjust your login call to use another provider e.g.

```
Membership.Providers["providername"].ValidateUser()
```

Comment: Thank you! This should work, however, the function call errors out when I pass a null object to the "object providerUserKey" object. 

"The error returned is The Active Directory membership provider does not support setting of the providerUserKey attribute."

Is there a correct way to call the method?

Comment: Ah, the problem was that I was passing a null object that I created as opposed to just the null keyword.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.providers.aspx) property on [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dazakw52.aspx) that contains a [collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovidercollection.aspx) of the membership providers.  You should be able to discern which provider to use from there.